# SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER in Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I am trying to utilize an Objective-C framework inside the Swift package. For this, I would need to import the headers something like

```
#import<Framework/header.h>
```

Traditionally this can be achieved via bridging header. How can I set the bridging header via package manager settings?

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: It seems the only way to achieve it is to convert your Objective-C header file to Swift interface.

Comment: You can have a dedicated target that will expose the interface which will be accessible but you main Swift target of the package. Please elaborate on which objc framework you use so I can provide more detailed guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bit tricky. You cannot import Objective-C framework's header files directly into SPM as you cannot write import statement such that ***#import<Framework/header.h>***

The only feasible way is, write swift interface for your header files in Framework and then you would be able to import all methods. It can be done with module map as referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771269/3307233)